# How does jtextarea.append(variable) differ from System.out.println(variable)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, file-io, jtextarea

i need help to differentiate

```
jtextarea.append(variable); 
System.out.println(variable);
```

Because i have this code that shows different output. Please help to explain and how can i make the jtextarea to display the output same as System.out.println

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int a = 0;

    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("MyText.txt");
        // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
        // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String line="";
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println();
            jTextArea1.append(line);

            for (String retval: line.split(" ", 0)){
                jTextArea2.append("");
                jTextArea2.append(retval);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(retval);
            }
        }

        in.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error while reading file:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.out.println to JTextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706674/system-out-println-to-jtextarea)

Comment: not use JTextArea.read() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two differences popup immeditaly.

`JTextArea` doesn't have any means for automatically appending a newline, whereas `System.out.println` does just that, it prints whatever you pass it and appends a newline.

Basically, what you need to do is append a newline character wherever you expect it...

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println();
    jTextArea1.append("\n");

    for (String retval: line.split(" ", 0)){
        jTextArea2.append("\n");
        jTextArea2.append(retval);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(retval);
    }
}
```

Might get you closer.

Comment: thank yo MadProgrammer, if you dont mind, can you also help me on how i can exclude words like  is,the,or and verbs from the text i have?

Comment: You could try `String#replace`