# using system.out.print() in a texarea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Am developing an application to query the table and print it out in the JTextarea but not responding instead flagging an error 'illegal start of expression' please am new with i need help and this is my code thanks

```
try{
  //get connection to the database
      Connection myconn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbt_for_java", "root","");
  //create a statement
      Statement mystmt=myconn.createStatement();
  //execute sql query
      ResultSet myrs = mystmt.executeQuery("select * from  jamb WHERE ID = '1'");
  //process the result set

     // System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));


  }
  catch(Exception exc){
  exc.printStackTrace();
  }

  BorderLayout questionareaLayout = new BorderLayout();
  JPanel questionp = new JPanel();
  JTextArea question=new

//this is where the problem is
JTextArea(System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));,22,111);
  question.setEditable(false);
  questionp.add(question);
  add(questionp);
```

Comment: you might want to use `setText()` or directly use `JtextArea("this is the text");` without `system.out.println()`

Comment: please somebody help

Comment: Um, @UmaKanth did help.

Comment: please share the error.

Comment: `System.out.println()` is used to print the string on the _standard output_, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: To change the content of a `JTextArea` use `setText()` or `append()`. However, if you really want to, you can redirect `System.out` to a `JTextArea`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706674/system-out-println-to-jtextarea

Comment: thaks @ Uma Kanth but i want to pass it as a String or variable please help

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println()` does have a return value, thus you cannot use it to set a value. What it does is write to the console.

To set a value in a textfield use the setText(), without the System.out.println

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the complex expression (that will not serve as a correct argument) passed as to the constructor of the JTextArea

```
System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));,22,111
```

Try creating a String first, then passing that in as a parameter, like so:

```
String text = "id" + "text" + "stuff";
JTextArea question = new JTextArea(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println` will print out to the command line you cant use it to set the text in a JTextArea you need to do:

```
JTextArea question = new JTextArea(22,111);
question.setText(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s=myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question");
```

here you will get your string in `s` now pass the string with along with other parameter.

```
JTextArea(s,22,111);
```

Comment: @ Roy James and Piyush Mittal thanks but it hasn't solve my problem instead am having errors at this line: at cbt.exam.examwindow.<init>(examwindow.java:169)