# how to fetch information from table and display it JTeaxtarea using java

Tags: java

please i need to fetch information and store them in the jtextarea please help
this is my code

```
try {
    //get connection to the database
    Connection myconn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbt_for_java", "root","");
    //create a statement
    Statement mystmt=myconn.createStatement();
    //execute sql query
    ResultSet myrs = mystmt.executeQuery("select * from  jamb WHERE ID = '1'");
    //process the result set

    //System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));

    //q=myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question");     
  } catch(Exception exc) {
      exc.printStackTrace();
  }
  BorderLayout questionareaLayout = new BorderLayout();
  JPanel questionp = new JPanel();
  JTextArea question=new JTextArea(22,111);
  question.setEditable(false);
  question.setText(System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));
  questionp.add(question);
  add(questionp);
```

Comment: You don't need the `System.out.println()` inside your `question.setText()` method. Simply use your String as the parameter

Comment: can you format this question ?

Comment: Duplicate of your own question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873037/using-system-out-print-in-a-texarea/31873119#31873119

Comment: See the answer I gave 6 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/a/31873119/928952

Comment: Start by removing System.out.println(), for it return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
question.setText(System.out.println(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));
```

`JTextArea`'s `setText()` method accepts String as a parameter. `System.out.println()` does **not** return a String! It **just** **prints** the String you gave it to the console. So, to fix it:

```
question.setText(myrs.getString("ID") + "." + myrs.getString("question"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(myrs.next()) {
   question.setText(question.getText() + myrs.getString("id") + ": " + myrs.getString("question")); //value in getString depends on your table.
}
```

If you want to separate the results, e.g. with line break, simply add "\n" between the two strings.