# Java: Printing Info from a method into a pop up scrollable window instead than to the console

Tags: java, swing

I am currently trying to insert text from a method named `printAll` into a `JFrame` that contains a `JScrollPane` that contains a `JTextFrame`. A portion of the code of the `JFrame` I created is shown below:

```
private JTextArea outputArea;    
JFrame popInfo = new JFrame();
JScrollPane scrollPane = null;       
popInfo.setTitle("University Info");
popInfo.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
outputArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
outputArea.setEditable(false);
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
```

The problem comes since I am using the method

```
 public void printAll();
```

which I first created to print to the console. I do not want to modify this method, but instead I want to be able to print all the content from `printAll`, as I said above, into my JFrame that contains the `JScrollPane`

Comment: So you don't want to modify the method? at all? You can then just probably set `System.out` to the `outputArea` so you won't need to change any lines.... That is assuming you do `System.out.println's` in the `printAll()` method

Comment: How do I set System.out to the outputArea? I don't quite understand

Comment: Look at this question asked and then the answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706674/system-out-println-to-jtextarea

Comment: thanks for the help!