# How to display multiple systen.out.println() from multiple classes into a single GUI like a JTextArea

Tags: java

How to display multiple systen.out.println() from multiple classes into a single GUI like a JTextArea.

Hi, I am doing a school project where I have a few classess that have system.out.println() to display the console outputs. However now I need to display the console outputs into a gui.

For eg 
class one has system.out.println("class one");
class two has system.out.println("class 2");

I have one GUI class, guiJava.class where it contains the JtextArea.

Anyone knows how to do this?

I read online is to use this code:

```
    PrintStream standardOut;

    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(jTextArea1));

    // keeps reference of standard output stream
    standardOut = System.out;

    // re-assigns standard output stream and error output stream
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);
```

But this appears to show only the System.out.println() in the guiJava.class, rather than all the sysout lines from class one and class2.

Comment: I recommend you study `Swing` basics from some good tutorial e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html

Comment: Study a tutorial like @ArvindKumarAvinash recommends. One thing you will find is that you do not use `System.out` to create a JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses the `PipedOutputStream` (code heavily borrowed from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522444/how-to-redirect-all-console-output-to-a-swing-jtextarea-jtextpane-with-the-right).)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TextAreaPrinter extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea outputArea;
    private JScrollPane outputScrollPane;

    public TextAreaPrinter() {
        setTitle("TextAreaPrinter");
        setSize(640, 480);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640,480));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        outputScrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        outputScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        outputScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(outputScrollPane);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextAreaPrinter textAreaPrinter = new TextAreaPrinter();

        try {
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new MyOutputStream(textAreaPrinter.outputArea), true, "UTF-8");
            System.setOut(out);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            textAreaPrinter.outputArea.append(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("class one");
        System.out.println("class 2");
    }
}

class MyOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
    private Reader reader;
    private JTextArea outputArea;

    public MyOutputStream(JTextArea outputArea) throws IOException {
        this.outputArea = outputArea;
        // Set the input to be piped to our output stream
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);
        reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
    }

    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        out.write(i);
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes, int i, int i1) throws IOException {
        out.write(bytes, i, i1);
    }

    public void flush() throws IOException {
        if (reader.ready()) {
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            int n = reader.read(chars);

            String text = new String(chars, 0, n);
            // Write the text to the JTextArea
            outputArea.append(text);
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this you will see those calls to `System.out.println(...)` in the `main(...)` function print to the `JTextArea`.

Also, if you already have most of your GUI and don't need all this code, you just have to make a `JTextArea`, and the crucial part of the code is this:

```
try {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new MyOutputStream(textAreaPrinter.outputArea), true, "UTF-8");
    System.setOut(out);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    textAreaPrinter.outputArea.append(ioe.getMessage());
}
```

After running the snippet above, all calls to `System.out.println(...)` should go to the `JTextArea`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

    PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new TextAreaOutputStream(area));
    System.setOut(stream);
    System.setErr(stream);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(area));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("test");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("test 2");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("test 3");
}

public static class TextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {

      private JTextArea textArea;

      public TextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
          this.textArea = textArea;
      }

      @Override
      public void write(int character) throws IOException {
          textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) character));
          textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
      }
}
```